# Translate SQL query to Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

Just need help translating this SQL query to Ruby. I'm on rails 4.1.5

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ab_splits 
    INNER JOIN ab_templates ON ab_splits.AS_templateId = ab_templates.AB_id
    GROUP BY AS_templateId"
```

First model:

```
class AbSplits < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "ab_splits"
  self.primary_key= :AS_id

end
```

Second model:

```
class AbTemplates < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "ab_templates"
  self.primary_key= :AB_id

end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That makes no sense. Do you mean translate to ActiveRecord, or DataMapper, or Sequel? Ruby can't do what SQL does; ORM libraries can. Also, without knowing your models, it's a bit hard to answer.

Comment: @Amadan sorry if my question is vague. I've very little experience with SQL. I was wondering if there's someway to translate the above query into something like this for Ruby on Rails: AbSplits.select("ab_templates.AB_id, count(ab_splits.ab_template_id)").joins(:ab_templates).group("AS_templateId")

Comment: Please post the code for the rails models

Comment: @papirtiger hope that helps.

Comment: So, I assume you'd have multiple splits per template, but only one template per split? Also, do you have any reason you are not following Rails naming guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're using ActiveRecord to do this (note `< ActiveRecord::Base` in your model files). It is a library that maps Ruby objects to a relational database (thus, Object Relational Mapping library, or ORM).

You will need to tell your models a little bit about the structure of your database:

```
class AbSplits < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ab_splits"
  self.primary_key = :AS_id
  belongs_to :ab_template, :foreign_key => "AS_templateId"
end

class AbTemplates < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ab_templates"
  self.primary_key = :AB_id
  has_many :ab_splits, :class_name => :AbSplits, :foreign_key => "AS_templateId"
end
```

When you do so, you can execute the following ActiveRecord query:

```
AbTemplates.joins(:ab_splits).group(:AS_templateId).count
```

You will get a hash with template ID as key, and count as value.

Note that this would be much less painful if you had table, column and class names that follow The Rails Way (with tables `splits (id, template_id)` and `templates (id)`):

```
class Split < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :splits
end

Template.joins(:splits).group(:template_id).count
```